# How to order nested fields with 'field_for' using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have used `fields_for` to show some nested forms, it works, but I want those forms to have another order.  Is there anything like `.order('attrib asc')` to use with `fields_for`?

I tried things like

```
form.fields_for :somethings.order('attrib asc') do | something_field |

<%= form_with model: thing do |form| %>


  { fields for thing }


    <%= form.fields_for :somethings do | something_field | %>
      {some fields for something}
    <%end%> <%# those are the nested forms i want in order %>


<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `order` clause on the `has_many` in your model, that will then be used in your `fields_for`

```
# app/models/some_model.rb
has_many :somethings, -> { order(:name) }
```